# How to select an option from a dropdown list using chromeless API?

Tags: node.js, headless-browser, chromeless

I am using chromeless API (https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless)
How can I select an option from a dropdown list?
Specifically I want to select last option having value="other".

My HTML is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with the [evaluate()](https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-evaluate) method which lets you evaluate any Javascript within the browser-context of any page you load:

```js
await chromeless
  .goto('http://yourwebsite.com/yourpage')
  .evaluate(() => {
    select = document.querySelector('select.decline-form-select')
    select.value = 'other'
  })
```

Or, specifically select whatever the last item is in the select list:

```js
await chromeless
  .goto('http://yourwebsite.com/yourpage')
  .evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('select.decline-form-select option:last-child').selected = true
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without the `evaluate()` method, too, albeit in a somewhat convoluted way. Avoiding `evaluate()` is useful when it is unknown exactly which events have to be triggered upon change, for the web application to work.

```
await chromeless
    .click('#the-select-element')
    .type('First characters of description text of desired option', '#the-select-element')
    .click('#the-select-element option[value="the-matching-value"]')
```

Or using the example posted in the question:

```
await chromeless
    .click('select.decline-form-select')
    .type('Oth', 'select.decline-form-select')
    .click('select.decline-form-select option[value="other"]')
```

Selecting an option using native Chromeless commands involves first clicking the `select` element, then typing text to select the desired option, based on the *visible text content* of the option (the first few characters that unambiguously identify the option should be enough), and then clicking the desired `option` element. Since it is not possible to find the `option` element by text content using css selectors, the element must be selected by some other means – e.g. value or ordinal number.

Sending arrow key presses instead of typing characters to select the option might work, but I found in my testing that using the `press()` method was buggy. (A tab with Chrome settings would open randomly while executing tests that used `press()` to send either the return or the space key.)

All this said, I was unable to make tests run reliably with Chromeless. There seemed to be problems related to scrolling elements into view or not. While the [webdriver](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/)-based systems http://webdriver.io, http://nightwatchjs.org and https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver are a bit more complicated to set up and code for, it might be worth the effort in order to get better reliability.